# Join two tables with different levels of detail and remove duplicated values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

Table1 (ID1, ID2, PERIOD, VALUE1)

```
WITH Table1 (ID1, ID2, PERIOD, VALUE1) AS (
SELECT 1,   'A', '202101',   100  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   'A', '202102',   200  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   'A', '202103',   300  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   'A', '202104',   400  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'A', '202101',   500  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'A', '202102',   600  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'A', '202103',   700  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'A', '202104',   800  FROM DUAL
```

Table2 (ID2, PERIOD, VALUE2)

```
WITH Table2 (ID2, PERIOD, VALUE2) AS (
SELECT 'A', '202101',   11  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', '202102',   12  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', '202103',   13  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', '202104',   14  FROM DUAL
```

The IDs are not in order and are not incremental. I would like to join the two tables on ID2, and only get Value2 values once for a given PERIOD.
How can I replace all duplicates that are the result of multiple ID1 items having the same ID2?

My current output looks like this:

```
ID1   ID2   PERIOD    Value1   Value2
-------------------------------------
1     A     202101    100      11
1     A     202102    200      22
1     A     202103    300      33
1     A     202104    400      44
2     A     202101    500      11
2     A     202102    600      22
2     A     202103    700      33
2     A     202104    800      44
```

My desired output would look like this:

```
ID1   ID2   PERIOD    Value1   Value2
-------------------------------------
1     A     202101    100      11
1     A     202102    200      22
1     A     202103    300      33
1     A     202104    400      44
2     A     202101    500      null
2     A     202102    600      null
2     A     202103    700      null
2     A     202104    800      null
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, assuming that `id1` defines the relevant order on the rows, one way would be a `NOT EXISTS` in the `ON` clause checking that there is no lower `id1` for a given `period`.

```
SELECT t11.id1,
       t11.id2,
       t11.period,
       t11.value1,
       t21.value2
       FROM table1 t11
            LEFT JOIN table2 t21
                      ON t21.id2 = t11.id2
                         AND t21.period = t11.period
                         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                FROM table1 t12
                                                WHERE t12.period = t11.period
                                                      AND t12.id1 < t11.id1);
```

Another, similar approach uses a correlated subquery getting the minimum `id1` for the period.

```
SELECT t11.id1,
       t11.id2,
       t11.period,
       t11.value1,
       t21.value2
       FROM table1 t11
            LEFT JOIN table2 t21
                      ON t21.id2 = t11.id2
                         AND t21.period = t11.period
                         AND t11.id1 = (SELECT min(t12.id1)
                                               FROM table1 t12
                                               WHERE t12.period = t11.period);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2b83e3e28fcae44caa6f7e865ac4ccfe)
Have a look which one performs better in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to enumerate the values.  Then include that in the `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_Number() over (partition by id2, period order by id1) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id2 = t1.id2 and t2.period = t1.period and t1.seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7da912527795bd895a563a20f6afd18f) is a db<>fiddle.